# Search through folders of html for user generated string.

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010,
Visual Basic .NET

I have been working on a program that has a JSON generated table of contents and a WebBrowser control that only displays the html we have given them.  Now I need to give them the ability to search for strings inside the html.  Not just the currently opened html page in the WebBrowser object, but the entire group of html files which are in various folder.

There is a Main folder with several folders in it.  Each of those folders only have one folder in it.  But inside that one folder is several html files.  (Not sure if knowing the folder structure will help at all)

I have no code for this since I have never done anything like this before, just wanting someone to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since html files are just text files you can use this approach.
To create this example I created 2 directories in my c:\temp directory, I named them InHere and ChildofInHere.  I put ChildofInHere in InHere obviously.  I then added a file called SomeFile.html and just put the word "Cheese" in it.  Here is the code I then created and ran against it.

```
Private _TextFound As Boolean = False
Private Sub Button10_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
    FindTheText("C:\temp\InHere", "cheese")
    MessageBox.Show(_TextFound)
End Sub

Private Sub FindTheText(sDirToLookIn As String, sTextToFind As String)
    If IO.Directory.Exists(sDirToLookIn) Then
        Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(sDirToLookIn)
        For Each dii As IO.DirectoryInfo In di.GetDirectories
            FindTheText(dii.FullName, sTextToFind)
        Next
        If IO.File.Exists(sDirToLookIn & "\SomeFile.html") Then
            If IO.File.OpenText(sDirToLookIn & "\SomeFile.html").ReadToEnd.Contains(sTextToFind) Then
                _TextFound = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

.NET makes working with files and directories so easy.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you much.  With some modification, I should be able to get this to work.  I don't know the names of the html files, so I have to loop through the folder to get each html file and read each file.